# Why would a new line directly after a <p> element add a single whitespace?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

A colleague had a text alignment issue on a screen I completed. I was shown the issue on a Win10 PC using Chrome, and some lines of text appeared like this:

```
Text line 1.
 Text line 2 is much longer and wraps to two lines, but the second line
does not have the whitespace added.
 Text line 3 does not wrap, and has the same alignment issue.
```

When I viewed it on my Mac using Chrome, I did not see the issue, so I ingeniously deduced it was most likely a Win-Chrome bug with some bootstrap class, etc.

But, after digging in, the problem ended up being the format of the `<p>` tag content:

```
<p>Text line 1.</p>
<p>
    Text line 2 is much longer and wraps to two lines, but the second line does not have the whitespace added.
</p>
<p>
    Text line 3 does not wrap, and has the whitespace.
</p>
```

I'm aware that a newline in the middle of a string will infer a space in most browsers (thank god), so that you don't have to add a trailing / leading space when writing multi-line content. However, I've never seen the initial return cause leading whitespace.

The point is that there may be a lot of code formatted this way, and the client will spot the alignment issues, as they test in Win10. **Why does this happen, and is it most likely a Win/Chrome bug?** Is it a conscious choice by some browser developers?

References would be greatly appreciated, but I personally could not find anything relevant on SO, CSS-Tricks, or Chrome browser documentation.

EDIT:
Another colleague has confirmed that adding a `<br />` within the `<p>` tag (no trailing / leading spaces) also generates a single leading whitespace directly afterwards.

Comment: Could not reproduce. Using Chrome on Win10.

Comment: Does those `<p>`'s has `white-space: pre;` style by any chance?

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap` would cause the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: I think you guys hit the nail on the head with the `white-space` property, and we have narrowed it down to some odd bootstrap inheritance going on. Since we develop on macs, we did not spot this until it was tested in windows, and we will have to dig into how many scenarios this affects. Glad to know i don't need to target win10 chrome though (or reformat thousands of lines of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`white-space: pre-wrap` preserves whitespace, so on word wrap it will not add the extra space since its located at the start of the paragraph.
either try `white-space: none;` or add some padding/margin if you want the whole paragraph to have that extra space even after word wrapping.